# How to calculate average growth daily in my storage?

Tags: php, space-complexity

I need to calculate the average daily growth of my company here in storage, but I have doubts, what would be the correct way?
Sorry for using Google Translator. =)

**Space Used in Storage:**

```
f_date      f_used
12/03/2013  2708100
13/03/2013  2708663
14/03/2013  2712155
15/03/2013  2715932
16/03/2013  2717823
17/03/2013  2719575
18/03/2013  2723095
19/03/2013  2726682
20/03/2013  2730365
21/03/2013  2733563
22/03/2013  2737411
23/03/2013  2644001
24/03/2013  2645764
```

**My code in PHP:**

```
for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
 $resultado[] = $array[$i] - $array[$i-1];
}
echo array_sum($resultado)/count($resultado);
```

**My result is:** -5194.6666666667, is it wrong?

Comment: I think it should be `$i = 0` in your `for` declaration for a start.

Comment: @EM-Creations Out of range when `$i = 0`.. `$i - 1 = -1`

Comment: @PolishPrince Ah yes, I see the way he's done it now.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is correct and is giving you the **average** of the daily difference.

Example:

```
f_date      f_used  difference
12/03/2013  2708100
13/03/2013  2708663  563
14/03/2013  2712155  3492
                     ----
                     4055
```

```
4055 / 2 (difference count) = 2027.5
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.org/RPmZUWjA)

Comment: Hi, my problem is negative diference

Comment: @user2207673 Then use `$resultado[] = abs($array[$i] - $array[$i-1]);`.

Comment: in its solution shows the daily growth of 10gb, this information would be wrong, I think it would be correct to calculate the average between only 2 days.

Comment: @user2207673 Thus the negative answer.